# Is it possibile to use Azure DevOps Server on premises with Azure Active Directory?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-active-directory

After reading this documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/about-permissions?view=azure-devops-2020&tabs=preview-page#active-directory-and-azure-active-directory-security-groups it seems that Azure DevOps Server on premises can be used only with Active Directory but not with Azure Active Directory. Is it correct? Is there a way to use Azure DevOps Server with Azure Active Directory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- You are right, as on-premises Azure DevOps Server, is built on a SQL
  Server back end which can work with on-prem AD .
- Azure ad authentication for on prem directly is not feasible as it is
  cloud based and involves azure based sql .

> **Note**: On-premise SQL Server only supports Windows Authentication and
> SQL Server Authentication. Windows authentication depends on Kerberos
> (or NTLM), which needs an Active Directory domain to authenticate the
> user in. Azure Active Directory does not handle Kerberos tokens.

- But we can opt to migrate devops server to azure devops services to
  work with AAD .[Migration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/migrate/migration-overview?view=azure-devops) is when one wants to completely move to
  cloud and it involves complex process as database/hardware is
  involved.
- If one wants to continue on premise server to use existing on-premises
  identities with Azure DevOps, you can integrate directories with
  Azure AD by using [Azure AD Connect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/whatis-hybrid-identity) which connects an organization’s
  on-prem Active Directory instance and cloud-based azure active
  directory.It involves On prem users to be mapped to AAD tenant.

Please refer [this Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/access-with-azure-ad?view=azure-devops).

**Other References:**

1. [PTA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/how-to-connect-pta)
2. [Migrate - Azure DevOps | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/migrate/migrate-from-tfs?view=azure-devops)